# SQL | How to always round up regardless of the last integer value, even when that may be 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

I am currently outputting values out to 6 decimal places, and would like to round up the 6th place regardless of the integer value.

I have been using a CEILING() function so far which has worked great for values 1-9 on rounding up; however, in situations where I have the 7th decimal as 0 (ex: 2705.1520270), the function does not round up to 2705.152028.

```
select CEILING(price*1000000)/1000000 as PriceRound
from tc_alcf a (nolock)
```

Comment: Because ceiling returns Smallest integer value. It is going to return 7 instead of 8

Comment: Why not return the raw values to your application code and perform the rounding there?

Comment: How about IIF(CEILING(price*1000000)/1000000 = price, price + 0.000001, CEILING(price*1000000)/1000000)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach:

```
SELECT ROUND(2705.1520270 + 0.0000005, 6);

2705.1520280
```

### Demo

[image]

We can add `0.0000005` to the input and then just use SQL Server's `ROUND` function to 6 decimal places.  This works because values with a sixth decimal place between 0 and 0.4999 (repeating) would become 5 to 0.9999 (repeating), meaning they would round *up* to the next digit.  And values with already have 5 or greater in the sixth decimal place would not be bumped up to the next digit.

This problem should be familiar to many developers as the rounding half up problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add 1 and use `FLOOR()`:

```
select floor(price*1000000 + 1)/1000000 as PriceRound
from tc_alcf a
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also shift the decimal by multiplying with the power function

```
CEILING(2705.1520275 * POWER(10,6)) / POWER(10,6)
```